# Can I ask for constructive feedback on a song I rewrote and sang over an instrumental? Looking to become better at music

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Can I ask for constructive feedback on a song I rewrote and sang over an instrumental?

I'd like to know what needs improvement from musically inclined people.

I'm not sure if it's okay to ask on this community. Thanks for letting me know!

Looking forward to being a part of this awesome community :)

Comment: Hi jack I've closed this as a duplicate of a previously asked question with a similar premise. What I will add on top of that, while it may not make sense on the main site, feel free to ask for feedback in our chat.

Comment: oka thanks so much

Comment: Chat's gonna be more suitable for this